# Why is my Custom Object Property in ApplicationUser null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a custom class called `Person` to store name, address, etc. This class/model is cross-referenced from other models, including `ApplicationUser`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

In one of my controllers, I use the following code to get the current user logged in and get it's `Person` object, like so:

```
        var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        var person = user.Person;
```

My `Person` class is also defined in the `ApplicationDbContext`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

When I inspect `user`, I can see that Entity Framework populated the object, because I see the user ID, email address, password hash, everything! Everything ***except*** the `Person` property! However, I can see in the database that the corresponding row is not `null`, but has the correct ID for the `Person`.

I'm new to ASP.NET/MVC/Entity framework and I've read that it uses lazy loading by default. Is this what I'm experiencing? If so, how do I tell Entity to use eager loading on the `Person` property? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you assign `Person` property in method `UserManager.FindById`...

Comment: 1) Have you added a `IDbSet<Person>` to the `ApplicationDbContext`? & 2) Try marking the ApplicationUser.Person property as virtual (so the proxy class can lazy-load it). -- It sounds to me like the DB doesn't know it exists as a relationship and may need to use implicit conventions/attributes/fluent model binding to tell EF about it.

Comment: @BradChristie 1) Yes, I have it defined in my `ApplicationDbContext`. 2) I'll try marking it as virtual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably a mapping problem. Entity Framework mappings are too complex for me to explain here, but I'll point out where the problem might be.

Make sure `ApplicationUser` has a foreign key property to `Person` in a way that Entity Framework can understand it. Entity Framework is convention based, so it will look  for a `PersonId` property in your `ApplicationUser` class by default. If you don't want to use the default name, you could use a fluent configuration on your Context's `OnModelCreating` to give it a custom name.

I personally think that it's always a good idea to manually map all your relationships. Here's an example:

```
public void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasRequired(m => m.Person).HasForeignKey(d => d.Person) 
}
```

Please refer to this link for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx

Comment: Well, that worked! I added `modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasOptional(m => m.Person);` to my `OnModelCreating` method and now it's working. Thanks for the help, @andrerpena!  However, I still don't understand why Entity Framework was successfully inserting the data into the database correctly before, but not reading it. I would think the insert would have failed as well.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out fine. Entity Framework was inserting data correctly because it was acknowledging the existence of Person, but not how it related to ApplicationUser.

Answer (score 1):

I would make Person class inherit from `IdentityUser` or `ApplicationUser`. Then, I would have the following in the dbcontext class:

```
DbSet<Person> People {get;set;}
```

Then you can use this:

```
MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();    
string userid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var user = db.People.Single(p=>p.Id == userid );
```

Comment: or he could just add all of Person's Properties in `ApplicationUser` Class.

Comment: My `Person` class is also used by other classes in my project that aren't necessarily `ApplicationUser`s, so I won't be able to inherit from it.

Answer (score 0):

In the entity framework code first approach the entity framework makes the first integer property as the primary key. So here you adding the reference of the Person class in the application User class. You can try this as:

[ForeignKey("PersonId")]

public virtual Person Person{get;set;}

public int PersonId{get;set;}

This will make the PersonId as the foreign key in the application User table.You can make it nullable also

public int? PersonId{get;set;}

From there you can get the Id of the Person object inserted in the application User Table and then you can get the properties of the person object.

I hope this might help you as this maps the relationship between two tables.